# Service layer in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have gone through the Laravel documentation and found that every request follows the *Middle layer -> Controller layer -> Resource Layer* flow.
But for my project I have a huge business processing logic which needs to be written. So, I am looking for a service layer option where execution control will be passed from Controller and then service layer will do the processing logic along with database fetch. But I didn't find anything linked with service layer part in artisan.

So, can you suggest me how can I implement a service layer in my project?

Comment: Can you show some example code to give an idea what it is that you want?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about creating a `Services` folder under `app/`, and use [Controllers dependency injections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)?

It would be something like this:

**MyService.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Bar;

class MyService
{
    public function foo(Bar $bar)
    {
       // do things
    }
}
```

**MyController.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\MyService;
use App\Models\Bar;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    protected $myService;

    public function __construct(MyService $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    public function handleRequest(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->myService->foo($bar);
    }
}
```